# Animate 2 rect together

Tags: wpf, animation

I want to make an animation in wpf, which zoom in 2 rectangle together like below:

Is there a way to group them together before the zoom in?

```
from this smaller image
```

[image: from this smaller image]

```
to this bigger one
```

[image]

Or alternatively, can I combine them into 1 rect before I do the zoom in animation?

--------------------- update ----------------------------

nobody answers my quesiton :( But I kind of find the solution myself. Maybe it is not the best solution, but it works. Instead of putting 2 rects together. I just place them on a canvas, and make animations on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, more C# than XAML oriented.

Provide names to the ScaleTransform and Slider to handle them in code.
No databinding.

```
<Canvas x:Name="root" Margin="20 20" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" >
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <!--ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=sliderScale, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=sliderScale, Path=Value}"-->
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" Width="200" Height="200"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20" Stroke="Black" Fill="Green"  Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Canvas>
    <Slider x:Name="sliderScale"
        ValueChanged="SliderScaleValueChanged"
        Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="251" Height="25" Width="273" Value="1" Maximum="2" Margin="74,249,170,45"/>
```

A ValueChanged callback to change the scale transform on the Canvas holding the rectangles :

```
private void SliderScaleValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    scaleTransform.ScaleX =
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = sliderScale.Value;
}
```

With the first XAML answer, and the second more C# oriented answer, you should have at least an answer that satisfies ;-)

Regards

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. So I am now animating (zoom in) on my Canvas. And I placed my 2 rects (or images) inside of the canvas, then do zoom in animation of the canvas in code. So rather than using <Rectangle> in XAML, I created 'Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle()' in my c sharp code. This should be equivalent to what you did in the xaml code in terms of performance, right?

Answer (score 0):

Both rectangles and other framework elements (like Texblocks) can be combined, using a Panel sub class ( like Grid, Canvas, ...).
Then applying a scale transform to the grid zooms both rectangles.

Here is a sample of code you can try - you can zoom in/out withh the slider :

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="root" Margin="20 20" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" >
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=sliderScale, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=sliderScale, Path=Value}"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" Width="200" Height="200"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20" Stroke="Black" Fill="Green"  Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Slider x:Name="sliderScale" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="251" Height="25" Width="273" Value="1" Maximum="2" Margin="74,249,170,45"/>
</Grid>
```

All transformations are made in XAML, but could done in C#/Vb.Net as well.

Regards

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is it possible to show me the c sharp code rather than XAML. What I am actually doing involves a lots of rectangels, so I have to create them in code dynamically rather than using XAML. What is the best container to contain 2 rects? I am currently using the canvas. Actually, even I have another container, I sitll need to put it onto the canvas, because I need to move/draw them freely on the canvas.